# WARNING: channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/community" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/community"

Tags: php

I am getting this error while installing the package extension key..

```
WARNING: channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/community" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/community" to update
downloading magento_mobile_assistant_manager-0.1.4.tgz ...
Starting to download magento_mobile_assistant_manager-0.1.4.tgz (16,531 bytes)
. . . ...done: 16,531 bytes
ERROR: unable to unpack /var/www/html/magento1420/downloader/pearlib/download/magento_mobile_assistant_manager-0.1.4.tgz
```

Comment: Did you run the command that it's literally telling you in the title?

Comment: where will i run the command? At magento root directory?

Comment: What command are you currently running? Run it there.

Comment: I have not run any command yet. As i am a fresher i don't now exatly what to do.

Comment: So how do you get this message if not by running a command?

Comment: ohh. are you talking for package installaion!!..  I am installing the extension key "magento-community/magento_mobile_assistant_manager" for magento connect 1.0 . you can refer the page https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemob-admin.html

Comment: I have not running the command.. but try to install the extension from admin panel ... from below path System->Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager .. and here i am installing extention key at  " Paste extension key to install:"